# Customer Tax Group not applied on order creation

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class

**Setup**

I have

1. Crated different `Customer Tax Classes` (Retail/Company)
2. Created different `Tax Rates` (21%/0%) and applied them with `Tax Rule`
3. In Store Config enabled `Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group` and selected correct `Customer Tax Classes` based on `Billing Address` and `Validate on each transaction`

**The problem**

In the store front everything works as expected. The prices during checkout are calculated with different `Tax Rates` based on the billing address with and without `VAT ID`.

**BUT** the `Order` is *saved* with the `Retail` tax values, even though the `Company` tax group is saved properly.

So both the admin `Sales -> Orders` and `API` show that order correctly with the `Company` customer tax group, but the tax rates are applied from the `Retail` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by modifing `app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php` by adding 3 lines after the first one in the following method:

```
 public function placeOrder($cartId, PaymentInterface $paymentMethod = null){
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

    $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false); // add this lines
    $quote->collectTotals(); // add this lines
    $quote->save(); // add this lines
```

This forces Magento to recollect prices according to the billing address before saving it to the database.